# Функция fread: остановится ли считывание при наличиии \0?

Tags: c, файлы, функции

Здравстdуйте! Допустим у нас есть файл. Мы его открыли, а потом считываем оттуда информацию с помощью `fread`. Вопрос: а если в файле есть `\0`, то `fread` остановится считывать информацию на \0 или будет дальше считывать информацию до конца файла.

Comment: Если не вмешалась злая воля У.Гейтса, то нули -- побарабану. Да и злая воля У.Гейтса вроде только на CTRL-Z должна реагировать...

Comment: @dimamephi, рекомендую в винде открывать файлы

     fopen(filename, "rb");

проблем будет меньше.

Comment: Интересно с каким файлом вы работаете, бинарный или текстовый?
По идее в текстовом файле не должно быть нуль символов.
А если бинарный то там нуль символ это обычный байт нуля и он будет считываться как все остальные данные.
Так же fread() не считывает файл целиком если вы этого у неё не попросите, она считывает определенное количество байт из файла.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос на самом деле не дурацкий :-) Вообще - чтение файла ф-цией `fread` не заканчивается при достижении какого-либо символа, только лишь при ошибках ввода-вывода или если файл закончился. Посмотреть описание ф-ции можно в справочниках. Например, [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) или [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt0etdcs.aspx)